# rewriteurl working on localhost but fail on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have made this .htaccess file after reading and testing many posts

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.htm [L]
```

it redirect the localhost URL

```
http://localhost/WCOM/Flatsome/blog/
```

to

```
http://localhost/WCOM/Flatsome/blog
```

. which is fine for me ...But on Web Server

```
www.*MyDoamain*.com/WCOM/Flatsome/blog/
```

is not redirecting .it refresh as same it is ..the page only render when I manually modify the URL to

```
www.*MyDoamain*.com/WCOM/Flatsome/blog.htm
```

Do web server need different setting from localhost ?
I am not able to find any post which differentiate these type of settings ..

What can I modify in htaccess file ?

Comment: check server error log

Comment: Did you set this: `<base href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>" />` in the header of your html page?

Comment: My href is plain ...<a href="../Flatsome/blog/">

Comment: The thing I said needs to be in the `<head>` tag of you html document...

Comment: I have search in <head> ... haven't  use this tag

Comment: Then put it there, TRY IT, and check if it solves your problem or not!

Comment: may by .htaccess is disabled on server..

Comment: How can I check server has disabled the htaccess . my server is godaddy

Comment: @Naruto I placed the link in Header ... the URL Rewrite to  http://%3C/Flatsome/pages/blog/